# How to create a django `models.Textchoices` programmatically?

Tags: python, django, django-models

How to create a django `models.Textchoices` programmatically?

In the [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#enumeration-types), it shows you can define a `model.TextChoices` with:

```py
class YearInSchool(models.TextChoices):
        FRESHMAN = 'FR', _('Freshman')
        SOPHOMORE = 'SO', _('Sophomore')
        JUNIOR = 'JR', _('Junior')
        SENIOR = 'SR', _('Senior')
        GRADUATE = 'GR', _('Graduate')
```

How can I create programmatically the same choices class from a list of key, values?

```py
mapping = {
'FRESHMAN': 'FR', 'SOPHOMORE': 'SO, 'JUNIOR': 'JR', 
'SENIOR': 'SR', 'GRADUATE': 'GR'
}

# ???
YearInSchool = build_model_text_choices(mapping)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#enumeration-types) to generate dynamic choices like this:

```
YearInSchool = models.TextChoices('YearInSchool', mapping)
```

and then you can call choices like this:

```
YearInSchool.choices
```

Comment: Thanks but this does not work, after running this, `YearInSchool.choices` is still empty.

Comment: @Mike i have already edited my answer have you checked the new code ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert it to a dict

```
mapping = {value: key for key, value in YearInSchool.choices}
actual_status = mapping[display_status]
```

Comment: I am looking for the contrary, to build `YearInSchool` from the `mapping`.